# How to write a grunt task which will check a url in every second, until get 200 or in 10 seconds

Tags: gruntjs

I want to write a grunt task, which will run some tests. It has 3 steps:

1. Start a server asynchronously
2. Run a task to check if the server is ready, by visiting the homepage of that server. It will check the homepage every second, until get status code 200, or fail if can't get that in 10 seconds.
3. If task 2 is successful, run some test files

I can do the first step by [grunt-shell-spawn](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-shell-spawn), but I don't know how to the second task effectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) isnt an option, or what server do you want to start?

if not just use [grunt-wait-server](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-wait-server)

so your gruntfile would look something like this

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    shell: {
        command: 'whatever your startup-server-script is',
        options: {
            async: true
        }
    },

    waitServer: {
      server: {
        options: {
          url: 'http://yourserverurl:yourserverport'

        }
      }
    },

    whateverTestTask: {}

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell-spawn');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-wait-server');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-whatever-test-task');

  // default task
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['shell', 'waitServer', 'whateverTestTask']);
};
```

Comment: `grunt-wait-server` is just what I'm looking for!